Why I am getting undefined while testing redux actions?
describe('Fetch robots action success', () => {
  it('handle request robot action success', async () => {
    const store = mockStore();
    const mockApiData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
      },
    ];

    nock('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .get('/users')
      .reply(200, mockApiData);
    store.dispatch(actions.requestRobots());

    const expectedSuccessAction = {
      type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: mockApiData,
    };

    const action = store.getActions();
    expect(action[1]).toEqual(expectedSuccessAction);
  });
});

This is the function I am trying to test
export const requestRobots = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING });
  apiCall('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((data) => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS, payload: data }))
    .catch((error) =>
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED, payload: error })
    );
}

it should give all the action but it is giving only one action when i console.log (action)  there are three actions
REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS, REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED  and REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING.
It is giving only REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING and for other action when i run npm test it is giving undefined.
giving me this error
 Expected: {"payload": [{"email": "john@gmail.com", "id": 1, "name": "John"}], "type": "REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS"}
    Received: undefined

      55 |
      56 |     const action = store.getActions();
    > 57 |     expect(action[1]).toEqual(expectedSuccessAction);
         |                       ^
      58 |   });
      59 | });
      60 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/actions.test.js:57:23)


I guess the nock does not intercept your api call. Show the code of the apiCall function

export const apiCall = (link) =>
fetch(link).then((response) => response.json());
this is the apiCall function I am using and it is stored in seperate  folder call api with file name api.js

To make it work, you need to know:

nock@beta support for fetch


We have introduced experimental support for fetch. Please share your feedback with us. You can install it by

npm install --save-dev nock@beta

Related issue: Node 18+: make nock work native fetch

Set the testEnvironment to node for jestjs:


By adding a @jest-environment docblock at the top of the file, you can specify another environment to be used for all tests in that file:

Instead of setting the testEnvironment in the jest.config.js file.

You forget to return the fetch() promise in the requestRobots thunk. See Asynchronous actions

Switch the node version to 18+ by using nvm like nvm use 18.20.3


The complete working example:
thunk.ts:
import { REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED, REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING, REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS } from './actionTypes';

export const requestRobots = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_PENDING });
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS, payload: data }))
    .catch((error) => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_FAILED, payload: error }));
};

thunk.test.ts
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

import { REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS } from './actionTypes';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import nock from 'nock';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './thunk';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);

describe('Fetch robots action success', () => {
  it('handle request robot action success', (done) => {
    const store = mockStore();
    const mockApiData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
      },
    ];

    const scope = nock('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com').get('/users').reply(200, mockApiData);

    store.dispatch(actions.requestRobots()).then(() => {
      const expectedSuccessAction = {
        type: REQUEST_ROBOTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: mockApiData,
      };

      const action = store.getActions();
      expect(action[1]).toEqual(expectedSuccessAction);

      scope.done();
      done();
    });
  });
});

Test result:
 PASS  stackoverflow/78952710/thunk.test.ts
  Fetch robots action success
    √ handle request robot action success (27 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.139 s

package versions:
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
"nock": "^14.0.0-beta.11",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
"redux": "^4.2.1",


@miogway27202224 Double check, follow the steps

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testEnvironmentOptions')
  at new NodeEnvironment (node_modules/jest-environment-node/build/index.js:88:49)

now giving me this error

@miogway27202224 Did you check my jest version?

"dependencies": {
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
"fetch-mock": "^11.1.1",
"gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"nock": "^14.0.0-beta.11",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"react-redux": "^9.1.2",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"redux": "^5.0.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
"redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
"tachyons": "^4.12.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18": "^0.8.0"
}
